# View doesn't shows backbone models in template

Tags: backbone.js, model, laravel

i'm starting with Backbone and Laravel, and i have severals questions because i don`t find anything in Spanish (maybe i don't know how to search, therefore it's easier to ask).

Here are my Models:

```
window.mMateria = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        nombremateria: ""
    },
});

window.cMaterias = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "materias",
    model: mMateria,
    initialize: function() {
        this.fetch();
    }
});
```

Here are my Views:

```
window.vMaterias = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    model: cMaterias,
    className:'list-materias',

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
    },
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).append("Renderizando!"); //It appears
        _.each(this.model.models, function (aMater) {
            console.log(aMater); //HERE IT DOESN'T ENTER, doesn't show anything
            $(this.el).append(new vMateria({model:aMater}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    },
    el: $(".container-fluid")
});

window.vMateria = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.model.bind("change", this.render(), this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }, 
    className: "item-materia",
    el: $(".container-fluid"),

    template: _.template($('#pl_materia').val()),
});
```

Then initialize:

```
    cmaterias = new cMaterias(); 
    console.log(cmaterias); //it returns 41 signatures
    vmaterias = new vMaterias({model: cmaterias});
    console.log(vmaterias); //Shows child {cid: "view1", model: child, ... 
    vmaterias.render().el;
```

Please help me and excuse my English, I dont know if Laravel with the 
`return Response::eloquent(Materia::all());` is the problem. Be as especific as possible. Dios los bendiga.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes.

```
window.vMaterias = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    className:'list-materias',
    render: function(){
        this.$el.empty();
        this.$el.append("Renderizando!"); //It appears
        this.collection.each(function (aMater) {
            console.log(aMater); //HERE IT DOESN'T ENTER, doesn't show anything
            this.$el.append(new vMateria({model:aMater}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    },
    el: $(".container-fluid")
});

cmaterias = new cMaterias(); 
console.log(cmaterias); //it returns 41 signatures
vmaterias = new vMaterias({collection: cmaterias});
```

Comment: Hola, it shows in console:
    child {models: Array[0], length: 0, _byId: Object, constructor:     function, url: "materias"…}
_byId: Object
_idAttr: "id"
length: 41
models: Array[41]

 --- But still show nothin in browser.

Comment: Is $(".container-fluid") actually in the DOM? Do you see the "Renderizando"? Oh you almost certainly don't want to get your template from `.val()`. Try `template: _.template($('#pl_materia').html())`, assuming `#pl_materia` is a script tag, right?

Comment: Yeah, i see "Renderizado", my pl_materia es a textarea, so it's right, but the 'console.log(vmaterias);' shows: "child {models: Array[0],..."  it means that the collection it's not correctly filled, but it has 41 objects inside, what should i do?

Comment: Are you rendering before the collection `fetch` completes? Might be time for you to make a jsfiddle. Stackoverflow works better for Q&A than "debug my code remotely for me".

Comment: I don't know if i did it correctly, but you tell me http://jsfiddle.net/bluesky777/2rr8t/4/
Please i'm feeling very bad about this, don't give up

Comment: Well your data won't load in the jsfiddle due to cross origin security restrictions but based on that code if your REST API isn't returning a list of model data as the top-level JSON response body, then you need to implement `parse(resp) { return resp.models;}` in your collection so backbone knows where the data is.

Comment: It doesn't work, 
 console.log(resp); //[Object, Object, Object,...
 console.log(resp.models); //undefined
so return resp.models; do nothing.

Comment: Hello, so, anybody could give me a detailed explanation of how to make a view thant render a subview? any page or somethig please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md